# Check array for content

Tags: arrays, bash

I have an array like this:

```
declare -A ignoreList='(
        [21]="1" 
        [22]="1"
        [25]="1" 
        [53]="1" 
        [80]="1" 
        [143]="1" 
        [587]="1" 
        [990]="1" 
        [993]="1" 
        [443]="1" 
        [2008]="1" 
        [10011]="1" 
        [30033]="1" 
        [41144]="1")'
```

Now i want to check if var $SSH_PORT in array ignoreList.

The var $SSH_PORT is this:
SSH_PORT="443"

if i try this:

```
if [[ -v ignoreList[$SSH_PORT] ]]; then
                    echo "$SSH_PORT is known"
                    exit 1
                else
                    echo "$SSH_PORT is not known"
                    exit 1
                fi
```

i get this in terminal:

```
443 is not known
```

but Port 443 is known.

so i try 
SSH_PORT="500" (not known)

and run the script:

```
500 is not known
```

he dit not compare

if i try this:

```
if [[ ${ignoreList[$SSH_PORT]} == 1 ]] ; then
echo In the list.
```

fi

it also did not work

my Bash version is 4.3

~# bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.3.42(1)-release (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Comment: Whats in `$SSH_PORT` ?

Comment: this is an var wich contains: SSH_PORT="500"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the associative array.

```
if [[ ${ignoreList[$SSH_PORT]} == 1 ]] ; then
    echo In the list.
fi
```

For the array:

```
found=0
for ignore in "${ignoreList2[@]}" ; do
    if [[ $ignore == $SSH_PORT ]] ; then
        found=1
        break
    fi
done
if (( found )) ; then
    echo In the list.
fi
```

Testing script:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -A ignoreList='(
        [21]="1" 
        [22]="1"
        [25]="1" 
        [53]="1" 
        [80]="1" 
        [143]="1" 
        [587]="1" 
        [990]="1" 
        [993]="1" 
        [443]="1" 
        [2008]="1" 
        [10011]="1" 
        [30033]="1" 
        [41144]="1")'

ignoreList2=(21 22 25 53 80 143 587 990 993 443 2008 10011 30033 41144)

for SSH_PORT in 22 23 ; do 
    echo $SSH_PORT
    if [[ ${ignoreList[$SSH_PORT]} == 1 ]] ; then
        echo In the list.
    else
        echo Not in the list.
    fi

    found=0
    for ignore in "${ignoreList2[@]}" ; do
        if [[ $ignore == $SSH_PORT ]] ; then
            found=1
            break
        fi
    done
    if (( found )) ; then
        echo In the list.
    else
        echo Not in the list.
    fi
done
```

Comment: Something is wrong
[code]
declare -A ignoreList='(
  [21]="1" 
  [22]="1"
  [25]="1" 
  [53]="1" 
  [80]="1" 
  [143]="1" 
  [587]="1" 
  [990]="1" 
  [993]="1" 
  [443]="1" 
  [2008]="1" 
  [10011]="1" 
  [30033]="1" 
  [41144]="1")'

if [[ ${ignoreList[$SSH_PORT]} == 1 ]] ; then
     echo "${error} SSH Port $SSH_PORT is not available, chose another one!" | awk '{ print strftime("[%H:%M:%S] |"), $0 }'
     exit 1
     else
     echo "was?"
     exit 1
     
    fi[/code]

Comment: @Dr.JoeBeer: `$SSH_PORT` is empty.

Comment: if i print the var $SSH_PORT i get the value. if i type SSH_PORT="500" i can echo $SSH_PORT and get 500 if i tye 443 i get 443

Comment: @Dr.JoeBeer: It works for me. Code updated with a script you can run directly to test.

Answer (score 0):

Starting in `bash` 4.3, you can use the `-v` operator.

```
$ [[ -v ignoreList[21] ]] && echo present
present
$ [[ -v ignoreList[23] ]] && echo present
```

With a value in `SSH_PORT`, you can use

```
if [[ -v ignoreList[$SSH_PORT] ]]; then
    echo "$SSH_PORT is known"
else
    echo "$SSH_PORT is not known"
fi
```

Comment: if i use this, i can use that:
if [ ${SSH_PORT} == '21' ] || [ ${SSH_PORT} == '25' ] || [ ${SSH_PORT} == '53' ] || [ ${SSH_PORT} == '80' ] || [ ${SSH_PORT} == '143' ] ||  [ ${SSH_PORT} == '443' ] || [ ${SSH_PORT} == '587' ] || [ ${SSH_PORT} == '990' ] || [ ${SSH_PORT} == '993' ] || [ ${SSH_PORT} -gt 1024 ] || [ ${SSH_PORT} -le 0 ]; then

i want to use an array to get the code compact

Comment: it dot not work :/ i use it but he do not Check i edit my question

Comment: Are you using `bash` 4.3 or later?

Comment: my Bash version is 4.3

Comment: Then I don't know what you are trying, because the code above works as shown if `ignoreList` is an associative array.